# Confused in understanding on tick range in uniswap

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

we know in uniswap v3 the tick range is `[−887272,887272]`. My question is, is this for each  price range or total of all price ranges should be in this tick range??

Answer (score 0):

Tick **index** range is `[-887272, 887272]`. This covers the entire price ranges.

With the base `1.0001`, powering it to the tick index `i` from `-887272` to `+887272` gives you a huge range:

```py
>>> # python 3.11 shell
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(1.0001, -887272)
2.938956807614301e-39
>>> math.pow(1.0001, 887272)
3.4025678683306347e+38
```